# In Python, Iterate over lists (or rows in dataframe) and pass values when the column value of rows changes

Tags: python, loops

I have a dataframe with two columns (Col 1, Col2). I want to pass the values in Col 2 to a function when the col 1 value changes.
How to accomplish ? The function will identify string similarity
I can have them in list or dict too based on options available.

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | Life Insurance |
| 123456 | Life Insuarnce |
| 789012 | ANZ Ltd |
| 789012 | AZN Ltd |
| 789012 | ANZ Limited |
| 13579 | HSCB |
| 13579 | HSBC |

For rows with 123456, I have to pass values in col2(Life Insurance,Life Insuarnce), find similarity. Then, when row value changes to 789012,I have to pass the respective values in col 2 (ANZ Ltd,AZN Ltd,ANZ Limited)

Comment: Are you working in a `pandas` dataframe, or `html` code?

Comment: pandas dataframe. html code came up when i tried to post the data in the format of a table in the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Is it always rows of two? i.e., `col 1` repeats values twice?

Comment: No, it doesn't repeat after two times. But mostly it does. In few cases it is 3, 4 times.

Comment: I think in order for us to help, we need a representative dataset. What do we combine in the event it repeats more than 2? There is not enough information for us to answer.

Comment: @wundermahn, I have updated with a sample scenario data.